# What real-life time periods were the First Age and the Age of Legends?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In The Wheel of Time series, Robert Jordan states in his post-book interviews (audiobook version, at least) that the "Age of Legends" and beyond are supposed to be similar to our real-life modern times. Their past is our present.

There are many descriptions that seem similar to modern vehicles and items to support this (trucks, helicopters, planes, guns, etc.) Some are from the First Age and some from the Age of Legends, but I can't remember which goes where. Other descriptions seems futuristic, even for 2018.

***What real-life time periods do the First Age and Age of Legends represent?***

Comment: Strongly related: [Is 'the age of legends' similar to modern day Earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36220/31394)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Since time is circular, it's impossible to connect Ages directly to specific periods in our history.**

*The Wheel of Time turns, and ages come and pass, leaving memories that become legend. Legends fade to myth, and even myth is long forgotten when the Age that gave it birth comes again. There are neither beginnings or endings to the turning of the Wheel of Time.* The Age in which the books are set is only *called the Third Age by some* - it could as well be the First Age, or the Seventh Age, or the *n*th age.

From [an interview with Robert Jordan](https://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=67):

> SCOTTY1489: Is our earth a future or past turn of the wheel?
>
> ROBERT JORDAN: Both. The characters in the books are the source of many of our myths and legends and we are the source of many of theirs. You can look two ways along a wheel.

Every Age referenced in the books is both in our past and in our future.

Comment: Of course you were the one to answer this.

Comment: Yet, it seems that everything is constantly shifting. The heroes who reincarnate do so in different bodies, with different backgrounds - but with a recurring theme and traits. The Forsaken were sealed together with the Dark One only this one time, and only Ishamael seems to be a recurring villain - if his own claim that he and Lews Terrin have been fighting the same fight over and over through the ages is true. No one knows how the wheel turns :)

Comment: That interview quote is very helpful. I was worried the answer would be 'wibbly wobbly, timey whimey'.